# Ограничить права доступа к директории в apache

Tags: безопасность, хостинг

Залил сайт на хостинг. Нужно сделать, чтоб пользователь не мог пройти по ссылки, например, www.site.com/images/

Нужно что-то искать в настройках апача или это можно сделать средствами php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Средствами php не знаю как, а вот в апаче есть в httpd.conf. Вообще в каждой директории создается файл специальный, в котором все эти вещи можно прописать, называется он .htaccess. Ну а дальше, думаю, сами нагуглите.

Answer (score 1):

1) Options -Indexes в .htaccess

2) Пустой index.html (index.php или что у вас настроено) в каталог /images/

3) В следующий раз прежде чем строчить очередной вопрос попробовать хоть немного воспользоваться поиском, эта тема уже тыщнадцатый раз, как под копирку...